# How to install Windows(8.1/10) when Ubuntu 14.04 is installed?

Tags: 14.04, boot, partitioning, windows-8, gparted

I want to install windows operating system on my laptop (originally came with windows, but deleted it because Ubuntu is better for me, but now I have to use Windows, because of my studies).

Few days ago I tried to install Windows 10 using USB stick, but couldn't because Ubuntu didn't boot it.

And that's where my question comes. I want to install Windows and delete Ubuntu just as it was before I installed Ubuntu. Of course, I tried to google this kind of problem, but didn't succeed. I'm not sure, but I guess I need to change the format of my disk, which is ***ext4***. [Here is the screen of GParted.](http://postimg.org/image/xr5z68bf1/)

Please feel free to share your knowledge!:)

P.S. If some kind of extra information is needed please say so.

Thank you, best regards.

Comment: Did you check the **Boot Device priority**? And, how did you create the pendrive? I use this [tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool).

Comment: That tool is for Windows only, I'm using Ubuntu right now. I am not sure if it's about priority if I want to remove Ubuntu...

Answer (score 0):

> Few days ago I tried to install Windows 10 using USB stick, but couldn't because Ubuntu didn't boot it.

So, that's a misconception here. Ubuntu won't boot from your USB stick. That has to happen **before** you boot Ubuntu or any other operating system.

First off, not all computers can boot from USB, they need to be sufficiently new to support this (the last couple of years should be fine).

Plug-in your USB stick and reboot your PC. What happens next depends on your PC (and the BIOS/UEFI).

Usually you will see a message like "Press *some key* to change boot device". So, often you'll see a message and it'll tell you what key to press to select a boot device. Sometimes you will only see a message about "BIOS setup" or similar and you will have to change the boot priority there.

What do I mean by boot priority? That's the priority of devices your BIOS/UEFI will check for operating systems (or boot loaders). On modern systems, the hard disk will often be the first. Since that's where your groub boot loader is, it won't continue searching.

If you tell us your PC model/manufacturer, we/I/you could search for the exact message.

EDIT:
I found a [list of keys](https://craftedflash.com/info/how-boot-computer-from-usb-flash-drive) for different vendors/models. F12 is very common

Answer (score 0):

You have already given the answer from the beginning. Does the following creates another partition in Linux 300 GB NTFS type - FAT32 and then try to reinstall Windows, I believe we will have no problem.

Answer (score -1):

Você já deu a resposta desde o início. Faz o seguinte cria outra partição no Linux de 300 GB do tipo NTFS - FAT32 e então tenta novamente instalar o Windows, acredito que não terá problema nenhum.

Comment: Please post in English.